# ANR in Android (Input dispatching timed out) (server) is not responding

Tags: android, kotlin

ANR in Android (Input dispatching timed out) (server) is not responding.  Waited 5003ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=true))

i'm not using **network** connections.

sometimes, occur this ANR. not every time.
i did search about this ANR. but i can not find same reasons..

i want know to what cases does this happen?

i don't have any idea about this ANR.
i can not guess anyone.... why happened?

why occured this ANR?
somebody help me, please...

```
E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.myapp.profindertest.debug (com.myapp.profindertest.debug/com.myapp.profindertest.HomeActivity)
    PID: 29952
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (2339a79 com.myapp.profindertest.debug/com.myapp.profindertest.HomeActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5003ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=true))
    Parent: com.myapp.profindertest.debug/com.myapp.profindertest.HomeActivity
    Load: 5.32 / 5.66 / 5.68
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.01 avg300=0.00 total=9675698
    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=1563915
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    
    CPU usage from 0ms to 7732ms later (2021-09-15 18:57:28.432 to 2021-09-15 18:57:36.165):
      41% 29952/com.myapp.profindertest.debug: 33% user + 7.6% kernel / faults: 25810 minor
      35% 2013/com.kt.tvcore.core: 21% user + 14% kernel / faults: 21391 minor
      23% 693/system_server: 13% user + 10% kernel / faults: 10493 minor
      16% 4044/com.kt.gigagenie.voicerecognition: 13% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 3038 minor
      6.9% 305/ktplayerd: 1.4% user + 5.5% kernel / faults: 338 minor
      5.6% 217/logd: 1.9% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 9 minor
      5.3% 551/adbd: 1.8% user + 3.4% kernel / faults: 620 minor
      4.9% 319/android.hardware.audio.service-droidlogic: 2.9% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 156 minor
      4.9% 850/com.android.systemui: 3.6% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 4250 minor
      4.2% 10912/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 3.3% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 3391 minor
      0.6% 538/media.swcodec: 0.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 7843 minor
      3.7% 1661/com.kt.tvcore.systemapp: 3.1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1038 minor
      3.6% 356/surfaceflinger: 1.6% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 376 minor
      3.4% 12267/com.google.android.gms: 2.4% user + 1% kernel / faults: 2640 minor
      3.2% 322/android.hardware.cas@1.2-service: 0.9% user + 2.3% kernel
      2.9% 348/genieaudio-service: 1.1% user + 1.8% kernel
      0.4% 537/media.codec: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 5486 minor
      0.3% 945/org.dtvkit.inputsource: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1342 minor
      1.9% 207/ueventd: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
      1.9% 2462/libAltiBrowser.so: 1.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 219 minor
      1.8% 874/com.droidlogic: 1.2% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1129 minor
      1.6% 234/vdec-core: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
      0.2% 520/media.extractor: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2895 minor
      1.5% 333/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.4-service.droidlogic: 0.6% user + 0.9% kernel
      1.5% 1728/com.ktpns.pa: 1.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 931 minor
      1.5% 3961/logcat: 0.5% user + 1% kernel
      0.2% 992/com.android.se: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 874 minor
      1.1% 9/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
      0.1% 1698/com.kt.tvcore.customizer: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 872 minor
      1% 162/crtc_commit: 0% user + 1% kernel
      0.9% 28197/kworker/u8:4-events_unbound: 0% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 11 minor
      0.7% 362/dtvkitserver: 0.2% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.7% 13214/com.kt.androidtv: 0.5% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 122 minor
      0.7% 24924/kworker/u8:2-adb: 0% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 24 minor
      0.6% 366/tvserver: 0.1% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.5% 1446/sugov:0: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.5% 29414/kworker/1:1-events_freezable: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.3% 828/com.android.bluetooth: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 128 minor
      0.2% 10/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 16/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 136/aml-ditest-0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0% 302/tombstoned: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.2% 304/es_out_task: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 310/statsd: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 136 minor
      0.2% 311/netd: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 52 minor
      0.2% 447/irq/23-fe330000: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 1569/com.android.providers.tv: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 38 minor
      0.2% 26658/kworker/u9:1-mali_jd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0% 28324/kworker/u9:2-kbase_pm_poweroff_wait: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1/init: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 21/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 26/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager:   0.1% 280/jbd2/dm-11-8: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 303/ts_out_task: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 332/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@4.0-service: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
      0.1% 353/audioserver: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 55 minor
      0.1% 2402/transport: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 3768/com.kt.tvcore.sode: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 4350/irq/19-fe330000: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 28607/kworker/0:3-events: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
     +0% 30008/kworker/1:2H: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 30070/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 30077/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
    62% TOTAL: 35% user + 20% kernel + 0.1% iowait + 2.4% irq + 3.9% softirq
    CPU usage from 36ms to 520ms later (2021-09-15 18:57:28.469 to 2021-09-15 18:57:28.953):
      53% 693/system_server: 20% user + 33% kernel / faults: 450 minor
        45% 29999/AnrConsumer: 15% user + 30% kernel
        2.5% 1395/IpClient.eth0: 2.5% user + 0% kernel
      55% 2013/com.kt.tvcore.core: 32% user + 23% kernel / faults: 37 minor
        23% 4802/Binder:2013_9: 14% user + 8.7% kernel
        20% 5400/Binder:2013_D: 11% user + 8.7% kernel
        2.9% 2378/.kt.tvcore.core: 2.9% user + 0% kernel
        2.9% 4537/Thread-114: 2.9% user + 0% kernel
        2.9% 5403/Binder:2013_10: 2.9% user + 0% kernel
      42% 29952/com.myapp.profindertest.debug: 23% user + 19% kernel / faults: 49 minor
        42% 29952/v.otshome.debug: 23% user + 19% kernel
      19% 10912/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 16% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 1052 minor
        16% 10927/HeapTaskDaemon: 12% user + 3.2% kernel
      15% 4044/com.kt.gigagenie.voicerecognition: 12% user + 3.1% kernel / faults: 53 minor
        12% 4349/Thread-39: 12% user + 0% kernel
      16% 12267/com.google.android.gms: 13% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 851 minor
        19% 12281/HeapTaskDaemon: 16% user + 3.3% kernel
      6.9% 319/android.hardware.audio.service-droidlogic: 4.6% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 4 minor
        2.3% 29868/audio_output_pa: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
      7.6% 551/adbd: 2.5% user + 5% kernel
        5% 551/adbd: 2.5% user + 2.5% kernel
        2.5% 605/UsbFfs-worker: 0% user + 2.5% kernel
      4.4% 217/logd: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
        2.2% 226/logd.writer: 2.2% user + 0% kernel
        2.2% 3966/logd.reader.per: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
      4.5% 305/ktplayerd: 0% user + 4.5% kernel / faults: 20 minor
        2.2% 16407/HwBinder:305_3: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
      2% 16/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 2% kernel
      2% 21/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 2% kernel
      2.2% 234/vdec-core: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
      2.3% 322/android.hardware.cas@1.2-service: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
        2.3% 3246/HwBinder:322_1: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
      2.4% 348/genieaudio-service: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
        2.4% 348/genieaudio-serv: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
        2.4% 4352/genieaudio-serv: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
      2.4% 362/dtvkitserver: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
        2.4% 476/dmx_data_thread: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
      2.4% 366/tvserver: 2.4% user + 0% kernel
      2.7% 1446/sugov:0: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
      3.1% 3961/logcat: 3.1% user + 0% kernel
      3.5% 24924/kworker/u8:2-adb: 0% user + 3.5% kernel
    62% TOTAL: 30% user + 26% kernel + 2.1% irq + 4.3% softirq
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or cause for this ANR?

Comment: @SuperCoder Did you ever find a solution.